# Javascript JQuery help PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have tried everything I could but the submit button isnt sending `something.php` the list of numbers that are added in the list.....

http://pastebin.com/0NexQW6a

something.php's code:

```
<?php
   $username= $_POST['SUBMIT'];
   echo $username;
?>
```

When user clicks submit the values in the list should get POSTED to something.php...[image]

Comment: what's showing print_r($_POST)?

Comment: Can you please give us the HTML? Why do you have two buttons?

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['SUBMIT']` stores the value of the submit button. You want to grab the username from the input text field form. I'm going to assume you named that "username". See below for what I did.

Change

```
$username= $_POST['SUBMIT'];
```

to

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
```

Comment: $_POST['SUBMIT'] stores nothing, because there is no element in the form with the name 'SUBMIT'. There is one named 'mysubmitbutton' containing the value 'SUBMIT', however. It can be accessed this way: `$_POST['mysubmitbutton']`.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins I would advise him to create a username field if that'ls what he's attempting to print out then.

Comment: ok i changed something.php to <?php


 
echo $_POST['mysubmitbutton'];


?>
Now when I enter numbers and click submit, something.php displays "SUBMIT" why wont it display those numbers T_T

Comment: @user807295 You need to read more tutorials. You're lacking fundamental knowledge about how forms work. Please start with this: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Answer (score 0):

If this is your form:

```
<form name="Rogers" method="POST" action="something.php" id="addForm"> 
    <input type="submit" class="formbutton2" name="mysubmitbutton" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
```

you either need to create a new input form:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="" />
```

of if you don't want it visible:

```
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="myusername" />
```

and on something.php grab the $_POST result with: `$username = $_POST['username']`